# Notepad++ Remove Text after String

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

my text from IEEE looks like as follows:

```
Spinellis, Diomidis, "The Strategic Importance of Release Engineering," Software, IEEE , vol.32, no.2, pp.3,5, Mar.-Apr. 2015
URL: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7057563&isnumber=7057030

Pautasso, Cesare; Zimmermann, Olaf, "Seeking Your Insights," Software, IEEE , vol.32, no.2, pp.7,9, Mar.-Apr. 2015
URL: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7057623&isnumber=7057030

Holzmann, G.J., "Code Inflation," Software, IEEE , vol.32, no.2, pp.10,13, Mar.-Apr. 2015
URL: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7057573&isnumber=7057030

Cleland-Huang, J., "Injecting Value-Thinking into Prioritization Decisions," Software, IEEE , vol.32, no.2, pp.14,18, Mar.-Apr. 2015
URL: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7057568&isnumber=7057030
```

I want to delete everything after the second ," and the first , " shall be replaced with - so that it should look like as follows:

```
Spinellis, Diomidis - The Strategic Importance of Release Engineering
URL: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7057563&isnumber=7057030

Pautasso, Cesare; Zimmermann, Olaf - Seeking Your Insights
URL: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7057623&isnumber=7057030

Holzmann, G.J. - Code Inflation
URL: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7057573&isnumber=7057030

Cleland-Huang, J. - Injecting Value-Thinking into Prioritization Decisions
URL: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7057568&isnumber=7057030
```

Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that every line if it has quotes has the quotes on one line, so you can't go far wrong with the match regarding whether it should match new lines or not.

This does it

Every line match "....." inclusive.  Capture the (...)

To match between the quotes including the quotes,

Find `"([^"]*)"`

Replace with `-\1"`

Note that "Regular Expression" is ticked in the dialog box.

The find portion, round brackets capture.  (you can say round brackets - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket  though they don't call them that in the US, it's pretty clear what is meant )

`"[^"]*"` <-- that would match everything `"..."` including quotes. But you want to only retain/capture part of that, because you don't want to retain the quote at the beginning.  So,  The find portion could have `"([^"]*")` or just the part within the quotes so `"([^"]*)"`  Then in the replace portion, the part in round brackets can be referred to as \1  And you want `-\1"`

Here is the after screenshot(after clicking "Replace All". First enter the Find portion, you can enter the replace portion too if you want. Keep clicking "Find Next" see it cycles them.  Then you know the find portion is fine, make sure the replace section is filled in as you want, and click Replace All.

[image]

**EDIT**

I just noticed you want to delete everything after the end.

You could do it in two regexes.  But to do it in one, you can match the lot (including what you want to delete), and just capture what you want

And if you see that `[^"]` matches new lines you can adapt it to [^"\r\n]

So this example, perhaps not the best way, but it works

Find: `([^"\r\n]*)"([^"\r\n]*),".*\r\n`
Replace: `\1-\2\r\n`

So you see in the pic it applied to the first one, and you can instead click Replace All and have it applied to all.

You can always undo and experiment e.g. apply to one line, undo, see it's what you want, then "replace all"

And you can easily add any spaces in the replace section around the hiphen/dash

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A manual workaround would be:

Find {,"}; <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>end</kbd>; <kbd>del</kbd> for each line

then Find {, "}; Replace all as { - }

Or other way around, whichever order you prefer..